# Test a program in b language

Tags: b-method

I'm not sure this is appropriate for stackoverflow, but I don't know where else to ask. For a program written in [b language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-Method),(Not the B language, predecessor of C and C++) and i would to know  if it's well written, is there a compile or test that i can carry out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with [Atelier B, the industrial tool to efficiently deploy the B Method](http://www.atelierb.eu/en/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Pro B](https://www3.hhu.de/stups/prob/index.php/Main_Page) to animate what you have written in Atelier B.